# How can I debug a rails "undefined method 'url' for nil:NilClass"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to learn rails and I'd like to get a deeper understanding how it all works.  And I may have some confusion about what should be singular and what should be plural.

I have a covers table in the database with 2 columns: url and path.

```html
    db/schema.rb:

    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150514120143) do
      create_table "covers", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.text "url",  null: false
        t.text "path"
      end
    ...

    app/controllers/covers_controller.rb:

     def index
        #render text: "hello from index in CoversController"
        # I can get this render message so I think the routing is ok
        @covers = Cover.all
      end
    ...
    app/models/cover.rb
    class Cover < ActiveRecord::Base
      validates :url, presence: true,
                        length: { minimum: 3 }
    end

    app/views/covers/index.html.erb:

    <h1>List Covers</h1>

    <table>

    <tr>
    <th>url</td>
    <th>path</td>
    </tr>

    <% @covers.each do |cover| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= @cover.url %></td>
    <td><%= @cover.path %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>

    </table>
```

When I navigate to http://localhost:3000/covers, I get this error
undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass

Is the trouble really that I am getting NilClass instead of Cover (or Covers?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<% @covers.each do |cover| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= cover.url %></td>
    <td><%= cover.path %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That did the trick.  Thank you. I guess I'll go back to reading more from the  Tutorial and the Rails way.